# When do the demonstratives ille, illa, illud become reduced definite articles?

Tags: morphology, vulgar-latin, late-latin, romance-languages

More specifically, what are the first attestations of the nascent reduced forms of the definite articles in Latin (or Proto-Romance) e.g. Latin illam > la?

Comment: I read up that an 8th century manuscript of the Salic Law has attestations of this kind, any earlier ones are welcome.

Comment: Can you add a link or some other reference to the thing you read to your question?

Comment: Apparently there's a 4th-century inscription from Algeria (CIL 8.19525b) containing the phrase *VT FACIA LVM MORTV* "to make him dead", with a reduced pronominal form *lum* < *illum*. Not yet a definite-article usage, but probably relevant.

Comment: 'ipsa cuppa frangant la tota, ad illo botiliario frangant lo cabo, at illo scanciono tollant lis potionis' https://www.orbilat.com/Languages/Latin_Medieval/Dag_Norberg/02.html